# SSL Handshake Failed Error 525 in Nginx: How to Resolve?

Tags: nginx, cloudflare, nginx-config

I'm encountering an SSL handshake failed error with my Nginx configuration, and I'm struggling to identify and resolve the issue. Here are the relevant details:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443;
    server_name sociio.org www.sociio.org;

    ssl_certificate  /etc/ssl/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/key.pem;

    location = /favicon.ico {
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
    }

    location /static_cdn/ {
        root /home/ubuntu/ichor;
    }

    location /media_cdn/ {
        root /home/ubuntu/ichor;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/ubuntu/ichor/app.sock;
    }
}
```

Any insights or suggestions on resolving this SSL handshake failed error (code 525) would be greatly appreciated.

Other points -

1. The webpage is working on the IP address without https.
2. SSL certificates are cloudflare's origin certificate. Cloudflare SSL/TLS encryption mode is Full (strict)
3. The website is deployed on Amazon EC2.
4. DNS is configured

I added SSL certs in the specified directory from cloudflare and that is it - restarted nginx and gunicorn but its not working.

Comment: This is not about programming or development and is offtopic, but for nginx to accept HTTPS connections **you need `listen 443 ssl;`** -- see the most obvious possible place in the documentation: https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#example . PS the cloudflare DNS servers authoritatively and securely deny the existence of `sociio.org` so you can't get any requests for that.